# Group Structure on Homotopy Classes of Homotopies

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

Given a cylinder object $\nabla : X \coprod X \xrightarrow{(i_0,i_1)} Cyl(X) \xrightarrow{p} X$ for a fibrant-cofibrant object $X$ and given homotopies $a,b: Cyl(X) \rightarrow Y$ with $Y$ fibrant cofibrant and $a \circ i_0 = b \circ i_1$ ("one ends at where to other start") we may concatenate them using the following diagram:

[image]

Since $X$ is cofibrant, $i_0,i_1$ are trivial cofibrations and $Cyl(X)'$ is a cylinder object again.  The main goal of this is to when the two moprphisms and the ends of the homotopies are equal we may form a group with this operation.  What I don't get is if this is an operation that should be defined on the the set of homotopies for a given cylinder object $Cyl(X)$ or in the set of all homotopies independent of a choice of a cylinder object. If the latter is the case, what would come to be the notion of equivaence of homotopies coming out of different cylinders?

Comment: I don't see how this gives you a group structure. Namely for the reasons you discuss.